# link to custom taxonomy by id

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

Through a series of specific requirements, I find myself needing to link to a custom taxonomy category using its term id...

I've got this - which displays a link to all taxonomies - I wish to change it so it only displays a link to the taxonomy with the term id dynamically pulled from a custom field I'm using.

```
$taxonomy = 'event-categories';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
if ($terms) {
foreach($terms as $term) {
echo '<li><a href="http:/mysite.com/events/categories/project-events/' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name .'</a></li>';
 }
};
```

essentiall I need "link_to_taxonomy_category(x)" where x = term_id

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

The function you are looking for is `get_term_link`.  It takes either a term object, ID or slug and a taxonomy name and returns a URL to the term landing page.

As a side note hard coding the link as you have in the example above is fragile -- always keep your code as portable as possible.  If the site is moved to a different domain, that link will break.  WordPress has several functions that generate links dynamically based on the current installation environment.  `get_term_link` is one example.

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link):

```
$terms = get_terms('species');
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'species').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Hi, thanks - wI have actually tried that, but couldb't get it to work, i'll have another go now. Hard code is just in there for clarity in the question...

Comment: yeah - can't really figue out how to use this - tried 
`$terms = get_terms('event-categories');
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, '20').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';` and got the following error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in..."

Comment: The second argument for `get_term_link` should be the name of the taxonomy ('event-categories' in this case).  It'll return an object of class WP_Error if the term or taxonomy doesn't exist.  You can catch the value of the error message by saving it to a variable (i.e. $term_link) and examining it before echo'ing: `if ( is_wp_error($term_link) )
   echo $term_link->get_error_message();`

Comment: I think I might be out of my depth here - not really sure how to use thid - sorry!

Comment: `$terms = get_terms('event-categories'); echo '<ul>'; foreach ($terms as $term) { echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'event-categories').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>'; } echo '</ul>';`

Comment: thats great - 'event-categories' is my taxonomy - and this lists all the categories in that taxonomy, I'm trying to list just one of those categories - identitfied by its term id

Comment: Then don't loop over the terms.  If you have a term ID, all you need is: `get_term_link( $term_id, 'event-categories' );`.  That will return the URL for the specific term you are looking for in the 'event-categories' taxonomy.

Comment: Sorry this just isn't working for me -must be a bug in my taxonomies as I'm fairly certain this is the right method - I've ended up working around in a plugin specific way - one that doesn;t really answer the question - thanks for your help though...

Answer (score 6):

If you have single `term_id` e.g: `10`, custom taxonomy `series` then you can use the following code to get the taxonomy term link.

note : change 10 to your variable for term_id and 'series' to your taxonomy.

```
$term = get_term( 10, 'series' );
$term_link = get_term_link( $term );
echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">View All</a>';
```

Comment: this only show default category and not custom taxonomy.

Comment: in the second parameter of the get_term() pass the taxonomy name.